# MultiLineString not working with Python's momepy.gdf_to_nx

Tags: python, gis, network-analysis

I'm trying to convert a GeoDataFrame containing Street centerlines into a graph.
I was thinking of using `momepy.gdf_to_nx()`, but apparently, it only accepts LineString, while my gdf has both MultiLineString and LineSting.

I was trying:

```
G = momepy.gdf_to_nx(Streets, approach="primal")
```

and got this as an error:

```
NotImplementedError: Multi-part geometries do not provide a coordinate sequence
```

I couldn't find out how can I convert the MultiLineString into LineString and still being able to later convert those into a graph.

How can this be done? tnx!

Comment: Use GeoPandas explode method, see https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode.html